# Permissions issue with AzureDevOps_Configuration during DevOps Server Express Update 1 Install

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

We just recently tried to update our DevOps Server Express with the Update 1 iso.  Everything looked fine until we tried to configure DevOps via the Server Configuration Wizard.  Under Existing Deployment->Databases we are getting an "Error retrieving setting from database 'AzureDevOps_Configuration'.  Verify you have the correct permission to access the database." error.  There are no issues noted in any of the log files concerning this database.  We've tried, I think, every permission on this database without success.  We've also tried two different accounts, including the person who initially set up DevOps and the issue persists.

So far, we have been unable to find any documentation on what permission(s) this error is referring to.  Has anyone seen this error before and solved it, or know where we can find the necessary information?

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps Server Express  need to work with **SQL server Express**.

First make sure you are using the right database.

Also double check you are using the express version iso for update 1.1, you could download it from this link-- [Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1.1 RTW](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/now-available-azure-devops-server-2019-update-1-1-rtw/)

Then follow steps in official doc: [Upgrade Azure DevOps Server Express](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/express?view=azure-devops)

Better give the account which you are using to upgrade full permission of SQL. Also give that account local Administrator permission.

If you still get same error after following all steps above, please also check **Event View** on the server machine. There may include more error info for further troubleshooting.

Comment: Patrick,  We restored the server to state just prior to the update late yesterday.  We attempted this update at a time when other maintenance was on going.  Now that that is done, we won't be able to attempt this update again until late in the year due to pressing EoY deadlines.  I'll keep this handy for when the time comes.

Comment: Hi @Chuck Thanks for your kindly response. Good to know it. Always better when you have a plan B.